# Mac to Mac SSH network problems

Tags: mac, networking, ssh, terminal

I tried having a friend and myself SSH each other so we could use the Say command to talk to each other in a fun cool way. We both had enabled remote login, but when the correct format was entered (*ssh Joe@192.168.1.x*), the error message "*ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.x port 22: Network is unreachable*" Is this because we're not on the same network? We are not. I am in Colorado, he is in Minnesota. Is this because of a port issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have public IPs (i.e. you're connecting to the Internet through a router) you may need to set up port forwarding on both of your routers to have the router send traffic on port 22 to the correct internal IP

Comment: Ok.......... What? What does that mean and how is it done?

Comment: @JShoe: It's probably more complication than the fun will be worth, but:  1. Have one of you find out the *external* IP address of your router, via http://whatismyipaddress.com/.  2. Have that person use the admin tools for the router to do a "port mapping" of port 22 to the 192.168.1.x address of their computer.  3. Then you can try to log in at joe@external-ip.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right it isn't worth it. But hey, I'm thinking this will kick ass at a LAN party XD!


Nerd puns...... never get old

Answer (score 1):

**The IPs in your `ssh` command are wrong.**

Assuming either (or both) of you aren't behind any fancy network setups, go to [What's My IP Address](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) to find out your public IP address, and replace the command with whatever it tells you.

Comment: Then go to the router of the destination machine and set up Port Forwarding.